# Are there any Python script /Libraries to generate turtle(.ttl) file from json file?

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf

I used Neosemantics to develop knowledge graph with turtle file.

Now I have some json data coming as response object and would like to automate the knowledge graph creation. I am searching for using a python script to generate turtle file out of this json response.

I had no luck in finding out any solutions. I would be thankful for your answers.

Comment: it's not that simple, you still need a mapping from the JSON keys/values to the RDF properties and resources. Indeed you could go the way from JSON -> JSON-LD -> Turtle, still you have to make it from JSON to JSON-LD which obviously depends on your JSON data format. Like if you have `{'birthPlace`: 'New York'}` what would be the corresponding RDF? What is the URI of birthDate then? Is New York just a string literal or does it also denote a URI?

Comment: I gotta see this library https://github.com/linked-solutions/jarql  which does the trick !!

Comment: jarql seems pretty limited, but hey, if it makes your life easier then good for you.